# Cant' launch pgadmin4 on ubuntu hirsute

Tags: pgadmin-4

I'm trying to launch pgdamin4 on my ubuntu device, and I just get this error again and again despite every solution I tried.

I followed this to install my pgdamin4 : https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/

Do you have any solutions?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py", line 39, in <module>

    import config
  File "/usr/pgadmin4/web/config.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pgadmin.utils import env, IS_WIN, fs_short_path
  File "/usr/pgadmin4/web/pgadmin/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, abort, request, current_app, session, url_for
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

Comment: Same issue here now. At first I had an issue with the python3 file. Got any fix for your issue?
Edit: I had no issue when I was on 20.04, but Ubuntu 21.10 is now giving this bug.

Comment: I have a similar issue on Ubuntu 20.04. No way to launch pgadmin4 on that system.